# Is it possible to set one side of Margin or Padding as to not override the default style?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I've set some default styles for basic elements in WPF that act as default styles for the application, this allows controls such as buttons to all carry a similar look and feel without having to adjust manually when defined, this also means that it only needs to be changed once.

A snippet of my resource dictionary looks as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,2"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Notice here that I'm setting Margin to 4 for all sides. This is great as it provides a gap between buttons without the interface needing to explicitly define it. I want to know how I can for a single button, remove the gap on one side without needing to define "4" for the other sides to allow it to butt up against the side of its parent.

I don't want to do the following as it deviates from the style (i.e. if I change 4 to 5 in my style I also need to do it here):

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="My Button" Margin="0,4,4,4" />
</DockPanel>
```

I just want to set `MarginLeft` somehow and leave the others as the default style I defined.

**NOTE**: I do have a workaround which is to simply use a named style of "buttonLeft" which is defined in the resource dictionary with no left margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your workaround is fine :)  if you want a MarginLeft Property you should create your own button and add this Property.

Comment: I thought I might get this sort of answer, thanks blindmeis :) I was thinking that I could get WPF to behave more like CSS :P I do have a `baseButton` style that my default style also bases on and then have the two named styles for `leftButton` and `rightButton` respectively. Thanks for the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Realizing this is already answered, I decided to test this in XamlPad anyway:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         MinWidth="500" MinHeight="200">
    <UserControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,2"/>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Margin>
        <Thickness Top="20" />
    </Grid.Margin>
    <Button Content="Test" />
</Grid>
```

What this seems to do however, is add the 20 to the 6, giving you 26 as top margin, and 6 on the left, right and bottom.

So, if I'd want 20, I'd have to put 14.

Comment: That's correct, as the grid contains the button and it's the thickness of the grid being combined with the button. Theoretically you could wrap the button in a `Border`, have the borders `Margin` property bind to the inner buttons `Margin` property combined with a type converter that negates the buttons left margin to effectively reposition it. This could be a viable solution, though it depends on which is less work :) The second is possibly less work to start with.

Comment: Ah yes, how did I miss that! +1 for that,